# How can I stop elements of an array loading on top of eachother?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I am developing a game for Android using AndEngine and I have an array of car objects that move from left to right on the screen in different lanes. When the car exceeds the camera width (the screen size), I set its position to 0 (left side of screen) - spriteWidth() (just to the left of the screen viewport). My problem is that the cars keep loading on top of each other due to the random coordiantes returned. I have tried many things, but it keeps happening.

This is the method used to set the coordinates of the car upon the game starting, and also going off the screen to the right.

```
public Vector2 randomRoadCoord()
{
    int Y;
    int X;

    int arrayLength = rManager.getInstance().roadPosition.length;
    int arrayFirstValue = 1;

    Random xR = new Random();
    int Low = (int) (5 *(0 - rManager.getInstance().car_region.getWidth()));
    int High = (int) (0 - rManager.getInstance().car_region.getWidth());
    X = xR.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    Random yR = new Random();

    int LowY = arrayFirstValue;
    int HighY = arrayLength;
    Y = yR.nextInt(HighY-LowY) + LowY;;

    if (firstLoad)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; j++)
            {
                while(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().collidesWith(rManager.getInstance().carArray[j].getCarSprite()))
                    X-= 150;
            }
        }
    }

    lastX = X;
    lastY = Y;
    return new Vector2(X, Y);
}
```

As you can see, random x and y values are returned between certain areas; specifically, the top and bottom of the camera (static camera, so basically the viewport), and between -50 and -450 off the screen (something like that). My issue is that I need them to stop loading on top of eachother because if there is a collision, the user loses the game. I try checking each cars sprite to see if it already collides with another car upon loading (though this defitely produces slowdown, and if it does, move the X coordinate further to the left, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
/*if (firstLoad)
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
        {
            while(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarX() + 100 > X && X > rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarX() - 100)
                X-= 150;
        }       
        firstLoad = true;
    }   */
```

I have also tried checking if the car is between x + 150 and x - 150 of the other cars, but this also doesn't do anything. Not all cars are loaded on top of eachother, but definitely more than 1, and this is too many.

Thanks. Please feel free to ask any questions.

--------------------------------- Update:

I tried using Plastic Surgeons advice, but the same problem remains. Though there is a much less likely chance of a car being loaded on top of another, it still happens **very** occasionally. i have commented the code this time, so it should be easier to understand.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; i++)
            {
                if(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().getX() < (rManager.camera.getWidth() + rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().getWidth()))
                {
                    // moves car from left to right
                    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().setPosition(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().getX() + (rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getSpeed() * 4), rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().getY()); 
                } 

                else //if out of the screen
                {       
                    //set the position to the left of the screen
                    rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().setPosition(randomRoadCoord().x, rManager.getInstance().roadPosition[(int) randomRoadCoord().y].y);

                    //if colliding with another car
                    while(collidesWithExisting(rManager.getInstance().carArray[i]))
                    {   //set a new random pos
                        rManager.getInstance().carArray[i].getCarSprite().setPosition(randomRoadCoord().x, rManager.getInstance().roadPosition[(int) randomRoadCoord().y].y);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The method:

```
boolean collidesWithExisting(Car pCar)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < rManager.getInstance().carArray.length; j++)
    {
        if (rManager.getInstance().carArray[j] == pCar)
            return false;

        if(rManager.getInstance().carArray[j].getCarSprite().collidesWith(pCar.getCarSprite()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks again.

Comment: ah i thought i did. all done :D

Comment: ok this hasn't been solved. that comment was to someone who deleted their comment D:

Comment: Ok, just so I understand it correctly: you are loading the cars outside the camera (randomly between x=-car.width and -infinity), and they should be on random lanes (y), right? when do they start moving and do you continue loading new cars, when they already move (and when after moving cars get set back to the left side of the screen) ? btw: sorry for deleting the comment :D

Comment: hello! thats all correct.. except for the between x and infinity. the lower field is 5 times the higher field (i think it ends up as -450). all cars are loaded at the beginning, and when reaching the right side of the screen, repositioned to one of those above positions. they start moving straight away after being loaded by adding to their x coordinate in the onupdate method (updated 60fps).  i've since tried a new method using spawn points, but if you see my error in this method, please go right ahead. and don't be sorry :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at least one problem with your loop:
The condition you check .collidesWith() does not change when the X value is changed. So additional false positives could take place.

A second problem is that if a collidesWith() event takes place, there is no way to know if the new x will also cause a collidesWith() event on another car earlier in the loop. Imagine placing a third car between two cars that are too close to accomodate a car between them. There is no way to resolve that in a single or double loop.

**So here is a different strategy:** Only make *ONE* axis entirely random. Step through the X axis (direction of travel of the cars) one car length at a time. Randomly determine if there should be a car in that position or not. If yes, randomly position that car along the Y axis. 
Without too much trouble you could make that accommodate placing one or more cars per step.

If you do not want the grid to be as obvoius, you could advance your X loop by 1/2 car length. Then you would only need to check for collisions against the car or cars placed in the previous iteration, and you would only need to offset on the Y axis to prevent a collision.

**Here is also a second strategy:** 
Place each car in a loop randomly. Test in a loop to see if the current car collides with any other other car. Keep randomly reassigning its x and y until it does not collide. 
At the end you will have an array of cars that do not touch.

```
   Car newCar = new Car();
   newCar.setPosition(randomXPostion, randomYPosition);
   while(testCarCollidesWithExisting(newCar)){
       newCar.setPosition(randomXPostion, randomYPosition);
   }
```

the "testCarCollidesWithExisting" method loops through an array of already placed cars and return true if the new car overlaps, false if the car does not overlap.

== Update with full example ==

here is a working example. The graphic used is the "tank" from the andengine examples. 
There is one warning: if you place more tanks than will fit, the script will hang, as it gets stuck in a while loop. I think around 20 is about as many as youc an do with that sized image and stage size.

package com.example.andenginetestbed;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class TestBed extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {

    // ===========================================================
    // Constants
    // ===========================================================

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 720;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private ITexture mTexture;
    private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_bed);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_bed, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_SENSOR, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        try {
            this.mTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("tank.png");
                }
            });

            this.mTexture.load();
            this.mFaceTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(this.mTexture);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Sprite> placedSprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        /* Calculate the coordinates for the face, so its centered on the camera. */
        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;

        /* Create the face and add it to the scene. */
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            scene.attachChild(face);
            face.setPosition((float)(Math.random()*CAMERA_WIDTH), (float)(Math.random()*CAMERA_HEIGHT));
            while(faceDoesNotOverlap(face)){
                face.setPosition((float)(Math.random()*CAMERA_WIDTH), (float)(Math.random()*CAMERA_HEIGHT));                
            }
            placedSprites.add(face);

        }

        return scene;
    }

    private boolean faceDoesNotOverlap(Sprite face) {
        for (int i = 0; i < placedSprites.size(); i++) {
            if(face.collidesWith(placedSprites.get(i))){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Comment: hi plastic surgeon. i tried using your methods, but to no avail. i have updated my original post showing my code (specifically, your first method. i tried the second as well but to similar results). thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I see one problem, I think. You are creating your array of cars before placing them. This is OK, but you need to have two arrays: one array of cars, and one array of placed cars. In your collidesWithExisting() you should only check against the placed cars - cars that are known to not collide.) And if they collide, then set a new x AND y position in the while loop.